# Can I buy a Steam game on my phone, and then just download it at the same account on my PC?

Tags: steam

I just want to know if I can buy a Steam game from my phone, and then just download it on my PC?

Comment: Are you using one of the [Steam mobile app](https://store.steampowered.com/mobile)?

Comment: What do you think works better?

Comment: I've never had any issue with the mobile app.  I believe if your computer is running steam when you purchase a game there's an option to have it start the install for you.

Comment: IOS or Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can buy a game now and download it to your laptop later.

You can either use web version of steam store - https://store.steampowered.com or their mobile app - https://store.steampowered.com/mobile . Just login into your account and make purchases as usual. Just don't forget to check if the game is available on platform your laptop is using (Linux, Windows or MacOS).